# Unable to actually write golang code on vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I've started using go recently and I cant seem to write any piece of code on vscode.
The only line I can write withou problems is the package one.
When i try to skip a line vscode doesnt let me. (for example, I want to go to line 3 so I press enter, vscode sends me back to line 2).
When I type import () it deletes it self (right after I type "(" ). And all I'm left with is package goexample. I dont know what to do.
I have go installed, go path configured, go extension installed. Please help.

[image]

[image]

when i type "(" to add the "()"  the second line is deleted.

Comment: What extensions do you have related to go?

Comment: @NigelRen Go
v0.40.0
Go Team at Google
this one!